# Add page numbers to the bottom of Word document in the format X of Y

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add the X of Y page numbers to the bottom right of a Word document. X being the current page number and Y being the total number of pages in the document.

I recorded a macro.

```
Sub InsertPageLabelsXofY()

    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\jhandler\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Bold Numbers 3").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
        RichText:=True

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub
```

This works initially, but after a day or so it gives me an error.

> *Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist*

The line that generates the error is:

```
Application.Templates( _
    "C:\Users\jhandler\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
    ).BuildingBlockEntries("Bold Numbers 3").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
    RichText:=True
```

Also, I would like for other people to use the macro. Is there some way to save the template in a public area?

Comment: See my answer in this discussion and see if you can't apply it to your situation. In a nutshell: If the file containing the macro is a template (and it probably should be if you're distributing it) then save the Building Blocks required for your macros, etc. in that template, rather than a personal building blocks template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in building blocks template is only loaded on demand, i.e. when a building-block it contains is inserted, [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.templates.loadbuildingblocks). You can force it to load by adding the following line to your routine before you attempt to insert:

```
Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
```

However, if you take the advice offered by @CindyMeister (and you should) you will not need to do this as the template containing your code will already by loaded. You could then rewrite your routine as follows, avoiding the need to open and close the footer:

```
Sub InsertPageLabelsXofY()
  Dim sectionNumber As Long
  sectionNumber = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
  Dim footer As Range
  Set footer = ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  Dim tmp As Template
  Set tmp = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
  tmp.BuildingBlockEntries("Bold Numbers 3").Insert Where:=footer, RichText:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: The 
Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
line of code made it work; thank you!

Comment: @Stomper please mark as the answer as this will help others

Answer (score 0):

To make your routine work, change the "Application.Templates ..." line to:

```
 Templates(1).BuildingBlockEntries("Bold Numbers 3").Insert Selection.Range, True
```

Word's building blocks template is always available as a global template, and the Built-in version is always the first template, so it has an index of 1.

Trying to specify the path to this template is what is causing the error. Yes, it might work sometimes but at other times it doesn't, so it is best to just use the index level and it has the added benefit of allowing your code to be transportable to other systems. If you tried to execute your existing code on a system that does not have your Home directory, "handler" then it will fail.

Comment: So I replaced the line of code with the one in your post and now am getting the error:

Run-time error '5941':

The requested member of the collection does not exist

When the program tries to execute that line of code

Comment: @Stomper, open Word's Building Blocks Organizer dialog and see in what template "Bold Numbers 3" is located on your system.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub AddPageXofYtext()

Dim pageNumber, TotalPage As Long
 
TotalPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) 
 
ActiveDocument.Styles("Header").ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight 
Selection.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Page " & Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & " of " & TotalPage 
 
pageNumber = 1 
Do 
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=pageN 
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous 
Selection.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False 
Selection.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Page " & Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & " of " & TotalPage 
pageNumber = pageNumber + 1 
If pageNumber = TotalPage Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```